# NameError using "finally: f.close()" together with "with open(..) as f"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code like this below in python.I'm using the 'with' keyword to open a file and parsing it's contents.But the error occurs when I'm trying to close the file.Please help.

Error message:"NameError:name 'f' is not defined"

```
try:
    user_xml_name = raw_input('Enter the xml name: ')
    xml_name = user_xml_name.replace(" ", "")

    with open(xml_name) as f:
        with open("temp_" + xml_name, "w") as f1:
            for line in f:
                f1.write(line)

except IOError:
    print print "File" + " " + user_xml_name + " " + "doesn't exist"

finally :
    f.close()
    f1.close()
```

Comment: Note the particular error message. It's merely a problem with scoping (although the whole point of using `with` is to avoid manually finally blocks in such cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to close it manually. `with` statement will take care of it.

So, remove `finally` clause:

```
try:
    user_xml_name = raw_input('Enter the xml name: ')
    xml_name = user_xml_name.replace(" ", "")

    with open(xml_name) as f:
        with open("temp_" + xml_name, "w") as f1:
            for line in f:
                f1.write(line)
except IOError:
    print "File %s doesn't exist",user_xml_name
```

Comment: Thanks 'falsetru'.That's what I also thought initially, but didn't find a documentation for the same. Can you please provide me the link in pydocs where this behaviour is mentioned ?

Comment: @manty, Official one is this: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Answer (score 0):

Here is a excerpt from "***Head First Python***":

"The ***with*** statement, when used with files, can dramatically reduce the amount of code you have to write, because it negates the need to include a ***finally*** suite to handle the closing of a potentially opened data file.
When you use ***with***, you no longer have to worry about closing any opened files, as the python interpreter takes care of this for you."